# GCD Strongly Polynomial Time

Tags: complexity-theory

I don't understand why GCD is not Strongly Polynomial Time?

Can you explain in an example, why the storage size cannot be Polynomial Bounded?

So is GCD in the Complexity Class P?

Comment: What don't you understand?  What are your thoughts?  Have you tried applying the definition?  Where have you looked?  We expect you to do a significant amount of research before asking -- if the answer is explained in [a natural place on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Strongly_and_weakly_polynomial_time) or follows directly from the definition, you might want to do more research before asking.

Answer (score 3):

As [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Strongly_and_weakly_polynomial_time) mentions, the reason that the Euclidean algorithm for GCD doesn't run in strongly polynomial time is that the number of arithmetic operations is unbounded, although there are always only two inputs. On the other hand, the running time is polynomial in the input size, and so the Euclidean algorithm runs in polynomial time. In particular, GCD is in FP (the class of functions computable in polynomial time).

Comment: but why do you measure the the arithmetic operations against the number of inputs and not against the input size like in the runtime? wouldn't it make much more sense to measure the arithmetic operations against the input size and the time against the number of elements?

Comment: That's the definition of "strongly polynomial time". If you don't like it, don't use it. In some cases it makes sense - for example, for some reason people really care about whether a strongly polynomial time algorithm for linear programming exists. If you want to know why, you can ask a separate question.

Comment: and isn't the number of arithmetics operation and the running time not the same? or whats the difference between them?

Comment: There could or could not be a difference, depending on your computation model, but in this case it's not important. The number of arithmetic operations is polynomial in the input size but not polynomial in the number of inputs. That's the problem.

Comment: i asked it in a separate question

Comment: But i then is also addition not strongly polynominally since you need to do more 'stuff' for bigger numbers.

Comment: In this game, you're counting each arithmetic operation as one unit. So addition is trivially strongly polynomial, since it's part of your basic repertoire. If you have a strongly polynomial algorithm then you can apply to numbers in any field, for example, without any penalties beyond that of actually performing the arithmetic. For example, you could work in an algebraic number field, something which might be impossible in a weakly polynomial algorithm.

Comment: So a problem where the input is a large sequence of small integers (0 or 1) but a solution involves huge numbers might by strongly polynomial but not polynomial?

Comment: No, under any reasonable definition, a strongly polynomial algorithm is a fortiori polynomial.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: You said that the size of operands doesn't matter, for example an addition is assumed to be constant time no matter what the operand size. I can write an algorithm that starts with small numbers but calculates exponentially large numbers with a polynomial number of operations. That would seem to count as "polynomial" as far as strongly polynomial is concerned, but "non-polynomial" when we look at "polynomial" algorithms.

Comment: @gnasher729 See the definition in the other answer. The algorithm needs to use polynomial space.

Answer (score 3):

The GCD *can* be computed in polynomial time. Strongly Polynomial is a much more restrictive classification. Taking [the definition from here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/7464/definitions-of-an-algorithm-running-in-polynomial-time-and-in-strongly-polynomia):

> An algorithm runs in **strongly polynomial time** if
>
> - the number of operations in the arithmetic model of computation is bounded by a polynomial in *the number of integers in the input*
>     instance; and
> - the space used by the algorithm is bounded by a polynomial in the size of the input.

The input to GCD is two integers. Thus, in order to be solvable in strongly polynomial time, GCD would need to be solvable with a constant number of aritmethic operations since the input size is constant.