# Is complexity of computing $2^{2^n}$ in P?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, turing-machines

According to [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/7485), given input $2^n$ (and thus input size $n$), this problem is not computable by a deterministic Turing machine in number of steps polynomial in the input size (though it is polynomial time computable under the Arithmetic model). Does this imply that the decision version of the problem is not in $P$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not specify what is the decision version of the problem you are interested in. I assume that it is the following:

Input: A pair $\langle x, k \rangle$ Where:

- $x$ is an integer of the form $2^n$ for some non-negative integer $n$ (encoded in base $2$).
- $k$ is a positive integer.

Notice that the input size is $\Theta(n + \log k)$.

Output: True if $2^x \le k$, false otherwise.

This problem is in $\mathsf{P}$. You can compute $2^x$ by iteratively multiplying $2$ up to $x$ times. As soon as the current product exceeds $k$, return false. If this is not the case after the $x$-th iteration, return true.

Notice that, in each iteration, the current product is at most $2k$. Therefore a single iteration can be implemented in time $O(\log k)$. There are at most $O(\log k)$ iterations (since the product doubles at each iteration) and hence the overall time spent is $O(n + \log^2 k)$, which is polynomial in the input size.

Comment: Thank you, this is the decision version I had in mind. As a follow-up, I gather that this does not imply that $2^{2^n}$ is "polynomial time computable"? Because it is not the decision version, the input size is $n$ and thus the size of the output is exponential in the input size meaning it must take an exponential number of steps. Is that correct?

Comment: Correct. If the input is the number $2^n$ then its size of its encoding is $O(n)$. The size of the encoding of the output is $\Omega(2^n)$, which is also a lower bound on the running time of any algorithm that computes $2^{2^n}$.